# Swift 1.2 subscript is unavailable

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, xcode6.3

In function, that perfectly worked in Xcode 6.2, now I have a mistake `'subscript' in unavailable: Indexing a String's UTF16View requires a String.UTF16View.Index, which can be constructed from Int when Foundation is imported`. This is the code:

```
extension Character {
    var keyCode: Int {
        return Int(String(self).utf16[0])
    }
}
```

And in this code I get the same mistake:

```
extension NSEvent {
    var character: Int {
        return Int(charactersIgnoringModifiers!.utf16[0])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.UTF16View` is a `CollectionType`, therefore you can get the index
of the first element by using its `startIndex` property:

```
extension Character {
    var keyCode: Int {
        let utf16view = String(self).utf16
        return Int(utf16view[utf16view.startIndex])
    }
}
```

(I don't have Xcode 6.2 anymore on my computer, therefore I cannot
explain why your code compiled before.)

Comment: @NikitinRoman: That is a completely different question. Please post separately.